# jQuery Validation for Login Form (Ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

For the life of me I can not understand why this is not working. I have the following code

script.js

```
$("#login").validate({
    rules: {
      username: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 24,
        remote: {
          url: "../core/login.php",
          type: "post"
        }
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        remote: {
          url: "../core/login.php",
          type: "post"
        }
      }
    },
    messages: {
      username: {
        required: "Username Required",
        remote: "Username invalid"
      },
      password: {
        required: "Password Required",
        remote: "Password invalid"
      }
    }
  });
```

login.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    require_once 'db.php';
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        $results = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        $hashed_password = $results['password'];
        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
}
```

So here is the issue. Essentially I am trying to verify the username and password via ajax as the form is in a pop-up. If no matching username is found on the database "Username Invalid" will show. This part works perfectly.

Now when I try to verify the password is where the issue lies. For some reason I cannot understand why it is not getting the `$username = $_POST['username'];`. But for example, if in the password section I manually define `$username = 'SomeUser2021';` it will start verifying the password properly.

Also if anyone knows how to display one simple error message instead of 2 separate ones like "Username or password is incorrect" that would be great.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and share it

Comment: Why use 2 remote functions ?

Comment: @IndraKumarS please advise on what would be the best way. I am not an expert with jquery validation. I am able to successfully set up a registration form. Just having issues with login form.

Comment: **Warning!** You're _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! Use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead of injecting variables directly into your queries like that!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you for the heads up. I will look into this once I get the chance. But first I want to solve my current issue.

Comment: There's no reason to use two SELECT's here. You should never tell the user which of the username or password that was wrong. Always say "invalid username and/or password". Saying which can give a potential hacker too much info (you've confirmed that there is such user) and also, they could have written the wrong username for _them_, while the username they wrote do existing in your db. You can completely remove the first `if (isset($_POST['username']))` block and only keep the second. Just return false if no user was found, before verifying the password.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes that was also part of my question :)

Comment: Well, combining the message should be super easy. If you take your first query, just put the password verify code where you now return "true".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson unfortunately simply stacking the if statements does not work. It just stops validations in both fields if done that way. Would you happen to have a working demo of this?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have also just verified and my current rules prevent any kind of SQL injection.

Comment: As far as the validation message part of your question.  You can very easily control the error message on your PHP side.  Instead of `echo 'false'`, use `echo 'construct and set a custom error message here'`.  [Refer to the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/): *"If the serverside response is a string, this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default."*

Answer (score -2):

Just replicating you code. If you want a single response "username or password  is incorrect" you can use one single function to verify both values.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    require_once 'db.php';
   if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$username'";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results)) {
            echo 'true';
        } else {
            echo 'false';
        }
    } else {
      echo 'false';
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
}
```

Also in you form validation you can do a single check o username and password .

Comment: There seems to be some errors in your replication. To begin with, you set username & password to equal $username in the SQL query. Secondly, you removed important code that verifies a hashed password.

Comment: This won't work since the OP seems to be hashing their passwords (correctly). This assumes that the passwords are stored in plain text (which is _not_ correct) This also promotes the same dangerous way of writing queries as the OP (injecting user data directly into the queries) instead of using prepared statements with placeholders, leaving you _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks.